# При oninput на <textarea> появляются множество строк <p>. При клике на <p> нужно получить его innerHTML

Tags: javascript, события

Имеется `textarea#text` и отдельно стоящий `div`. При вводе текста (`oninput`) формируется ajax-запрос, который выводит в `div` (ранее совершенно пустой) строки до 600 штук (`p.matches`), в которых встречаются символы из `textarea`. Мне нужно при двойном клике на любой из p.matches вывести в консоль его `innerHTML`. Не могу связать два фрагмента кода в один...

Первый:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var text = document.querySelector('#text');
    var old_classifieds = document.querySelector('#old_classifieds');

    text.oninput = function(){
        var find = 'find=' + text.value;

        var xhr3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr3.open('POST', 'findPhone.php');
        xhr3.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr3.send(find);

        xhr3.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr3.readyState == 4 && xhr3.status == 200){
                old_classifieds.innerHTML = xhr3.response;
            }       
            else{
                old_classifieds.innerHTML = 'Ошибка!';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Второй:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('p.matches');
matches.forEach(function(item){
    item.ondblclick = function(){
        console.log(item.innerHTML);
    }
})
```

Думаю, дело в том, что при загрузке страницы p.matches еще не существуют и формируются php-обработчиком. Но когда они есть и в консоль ввести код номер 2, то все начинает работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
...
if(xhr3.readyState == 4 && xhr3.status == 200){
  old_classifieds.innerHTML = xhr3.response;

  var matches = document.querySelectorAll('p.matches');
  matches.forEach(function(item){
    item.ondblclick = function(){
      console.log(item.innerHTML);
    }
  });
}       
...
```

Вариант 2:

```js
var old_classifieds = document.querySelector('#old_classifieds');

old_classifieds.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "P" && e.target.classList.contains("matches")) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="old_classifieds">
  <p class="matches">The walrus and the carpenter</p>
  <p class="matches">Walked for a mile or so...</p>
</div>
```